# Video is ignoring CSS height and width values

Tags: css, wordpress, height, width, shortcode

The video, and all videos i add to my page has height and width values set in CSS (via a shortcode) but it is just ignoring them. wasnt a problem yesterday and i have no idea what issue is: http://focallocal.org/open-skills-sharing/

here's the code:

```
[su_youtube_advanced url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N0B4CL0GIpU&amp;list=PLzwMXFvS_OYPOIGeR9sM58sNW9U04qsAd " width="500px" height="400px" responsive="no" autoplay="yes" modestbranding="yes" class="float: right;"][su_youtube_advanced url="https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLzwMXFvS_OYPSL9J1P9W9RaP304UDM6IY" autoplay="yes" rel="no" modestbranding="yes"][/su_youtube_advanced]
```

can anyone see whats causing it, or suggest some code to force it to stay at the set size/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your video is wrapped in a `div` with a class of `flex-video` which appears to be trying to make your video size responsive (i.e. 100% width and 100% height).  The style is defined in `core.css` on lines 63 & 64.

It looks like your `style.css` is loading after `core.css` so you should be able to override that style if you wish.  For example:

```
.flex-video iframe {
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

On a side note, it's a little difficult to pinpoint exactly what's going on.  You have 36 stylesheets loading.  (And 289 total requests).  Ideally you'll want your requests to be under 10.